# How to SELECT by DATE from DATETIME table AND group by date

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `count_traffic` (
  `tool_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `leads` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And following SELECT:

```
$query="
SELECT sum(`leads`) as leads
     , date  
  FROM count_traffic 
 WHERE tool_id = :tool_id  
   AND date BETWEEN '2018-03-13' AND '2018-03-14' 
 GROUP 
    BY date";
```

This SELECT it show me good results if I use `date` for date field! How I can SELECT BETWEEN two dates and GROUP BY DATE only from `datetime` field type?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You use the [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function and wrap your `date` column in that function call.

```
SELECT sum(`leads`) as leads
     , DATE(`date`)
  FROM count_traffic 
 WHERE tool_id = :tool_id  
   AND date BETWEEN '2018-03-13' AND '2018-03-14' 
 GROUP 
    BY DATE(`date`)
```

Comment: I have tried your SELECT in PHPMYADMIN but it return me empty result in two columns       `leads  DATE(date)`

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution, this is SELECT for who need too:

```
SELECT sum(`leads`) as leads, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d') as date 
FROM count_traffic 
WHERE 
        tool_id = :tool_id  
    AND 
        DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-03-13' AND '2018-03-14' 
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Below i've attached the fiddle link.... You check it...
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b1ebb/6

Comment: it is any performance different when is high number of data between your SELECT and my SELECT https://stackoverflow.com/a/49278296/9490909 because both are working?